# Can moderators edit comments?

Tags: support, edits, comments, moderators

I had a discussion on one of my answers (basically the OP kept asking more stuff and didn't accept that my answer was correct) and I ended up linking to the [Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com), but for an unknown reason the parser on SO's side did not recognize the link and instead my comment showed the link formatting like this:

> Flagged for moderator attention for comment cleanup. @MeirGoldenberg If you want a discussion, use the *`[Chat Facility provided](chat.stackoverflow.com)`*.

I realize now that it was most likely because I missed out the `http://` on the link.

I ended up flagging my answer for moderator attention requesting comment clean-up as it got messy, I came back to the answer and now *the link is properly formatted*:

[image]

Did the system magically correct my link, or did a moderator fix it?

Do moderators possess the ability to edit comments?

Comment: Moderators can edit comments, yes.

Comment: Yes -- see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33939/253560

Comment: Yes, they can, and they are not subject to the five-minute limit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, moderators can edit comments.

However, we don't usually do so because it leaves no audit trail and in some eyes smacks of putting words into people's mouths.

In this case, however, I would assume that the moderator saw the missing `http://` and was happy to add it.

However, it's almost always easier for you to just delete the original and repost the corrected version of the comment. The only time when this might not be the case would be if you really need to preserve the comment order, but those times should be very few and far between.